# Dataloader: upsert a Lookupfield

Tags: data-loader

How do I upsert data with dataloader to a custom object?

I have one Lookup field ("Class id") in the record that course trubble: I get following error notifications: "Class id: id value of incorrect type: B99"

What do I have to do to be able to fill this field?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are passing the wrong value. Salesforce ID can be only 15 or 18 chars but you are passing only 3 chars, you should map data correctly from your csv while using dataloader.